# Libgdx applyforce to mouse or finger direction

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I want to drag dynamic object with a finger or mouse so that don't ruin collision detection,

body.setTransform() behavior is the exact thing what I need but when I use it collisions don't work and I can move body through static bodies.

I tried to use mousejoint but I just cant figure out how it works, some people suggested to check box2d testbed to understand mousejoint but it became nightmare for me, I'm missing something fundamental I think.

I tried applyForce and applyLinearImpulse too but I don't understand how they work, I cant move body to the mouse direction, it just bounces here and there and I cant predict its behaviour.

Now I think I lack some fundamental understanding of box2d and I have to learn basic ideas but before I do that I need this thing done very quickly and good example with source code would be great or some explanation  how I can achieve dragging object with one of these or any other methods.

Thanks.

Comment: I think applyLinearImpuse will do.. You just have to calculate the direction and applyLinear Impulse to it.

Answer (score 1):

*edit - talking about setTransform first*

First thing you should know is that setTransform essentially turns off the box2D physics on the object you're messing with. So if you want your movement to look smooth and natural, it's a good idea to avoid this method where possible (although it has its uses).

I don't know much about android gestures, but this is how I would do it with a mouse. It's probably not much different except you're detecting touchdown instead of a mouse click.

1. Get the change in x and the change in y coordinates. Call that delta x and delta y. You could do this most easily (although some would argue not ideally) in your gdx render method, updating every however many milliseconds.
2. Get the angle theta based on your delta x and deltay. Since tan(theta) = deltay/deltax, then arctan(deltay/deltax) will give you your angle, theta, in radians.
3. Find out how to detect whether your object has been clicked and held on. I would use the existing java methods for detecting whether a set of coordinates is within a shape. I'm pretty sure libGDX has some similar functionality in their shape libraries, but if not, just use java shapes and sync them with your game objects. Box2d may have methods for this too. It's not a difficult problem to solve.
4. Use this box2d method on the box2d body of the object being manipulated:

   ```
   myObjectBody.applyForceToCenter(new Vector2((float)Math.cos(myMouseDirectionAngle) 
   * forceYouWantToApply, (float)Math.sin(myMouseDirectionAngle) * forceYouWantToApply));
   ```

Note: You may also need to set the body of your object to 'wake' by setting the wake parameter of the applyForceToCenter method to true.